# How to delete with no check foreign key constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some bad data in SQL. this table has a lot of relationship with other tables and other tables have a lot of data so when I want to delete bad data it's very slowly and take lots of time to do. I think the cause of this problem is foreign key constraints. the main problem is how can disable all of the foreign key constraints from one table.

Comment: You are using MySQL and not SQL Server, right?

Comment: NO I  USE SQL SERVER

Comment: that is write but i get an idea from selected and changed it I am new in stack so accepted it

Answer (score -1):

You have to disable check constraint:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Make sure to turn it back after your commands:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Disable constraint for one table:

```
alter table
   table_name
DISABLE constraint
   constraint_name;
```

Here is an example:

```
select 'alter table '||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name||';' from user_constraints;
```

Comment: is it any way for one table not all tables?

Comment: @o.man: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is a MySQL command.

Comment: @aliazizan . . . I'm baffled as to how an answers that doesn't workin the tagged database can be accepted.  This is not SQL Server code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is write but i get an idea from selected and changed it I am new in stack so accepted it